# Unicode setlocale and strftime fails at windows

Tags: php, windows, unicode, strftime, setlocale

I have one page and it's encoding is UTF-8 and If i try to run that code in unix system everythings looks fine but when i try to run in windows(7) some chracters looks question mark(�). How can run the code fine both of two system(without using iconv).

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'turkish');
echo strftime("%d %B %Y, %H:%M");
```

Comment: Is the ONLY difference the server?  Not the browser, the FTP program or the editor saving it?  I know it's sounds strange but if your editor is set in a different char set, or the browser's default charset can affect it.  It's a pain the butt sometimes.

Comment: Yes, only difference is server. Encoding types for all files are same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who is having similar problems on linux (this may work also for windows but not sure).

Yes there is 'turkish' but there is also 'tr_TR.utf8' . If you use 'tr_TR.utf8' most probably your problems will be washed away. Same thing applies also to 'greek'. Instead use 'el_GR.utf8'

On linux you can check the locale list to find the proper settings for your site.

```
locale -a
```

List is too long and you can't see all languages, so either you can just dump it into a file and then open the file to check.

```
locale -a > locale.txt
vi locale.txt
```

or do ***locale -a | grep languagecode*** for a specific language

```
locale -a | grep tr
```

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft Windows does not support UTF-8 locales. So if you provide turkish locale, it would pic an 8-bit code page that allows representation of specific language.

For example for locale Hebrew it would pic codepage-1255, for Turkish it would probably be 1254.

So, you can't use this under MS-Windows platform.

> How can run the code fine both of two system(without using iconv).

Probably use non-utf8 encoding under MS Windows.