# PHP day of week numeric to day of week text not English

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, setlocale

I tried to use `setlocale()` function on windows to convert days name in other language but it didn't work.

```
<?php setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL'); 
echo date("l", strtotime($variable); ?>
```

does anybody have an alternative for `setlocale()`? I use the Codeigniter framework.

Comment: What's wrong with `setlocale`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unicode setlocale and strftime fails at windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197168/unicode-setlocale-and-strftime-fails-at-windows) - you didn't share which of the two causes were your actual problem: wrong locale name *or* using `date` *or* both. Please share what helped with your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nl_NL` is a typical Unix style locale name. On Windows, locales follow a [different format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php#refsect1-function.setlocale-notes). You want ["nld", "holland", or "netherlands"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Additionally, `date()` is not locale-aware. You probably want `strftime()`.

Answer (score 5):

You should consider using the extension `intl` which has `IntlDateFormatter`.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.format.php):

```
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter( "en_US" ,IntlDateFormatter::FULL,IntlDateFormatter::FULL,'America/Los_Angeles',IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN  );
echo "First Formatted output is ".$fmt->format(0);
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter( "de-DE" ,IntlDateFormatter::FULL,IntlDateFormatter::FULL,'America/Los_Angeles',IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN  );
echo "Second Formatted output is ".$fmt->format(0);
```

which output

```
First Formatted output is Wednesday, December 31, 1969 4:00:00 PM PT
Second Formatted output is Mittwoch, 31. Dezember 1969 16:00 Uhr GMT-08:00
```

Comment: Pattern based formatting shown in a similar question: [Localized (short) month names using IntlDateFormatter in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13992296/367456)

Answer (score 2):

`date` does not format dates according to locale. [`strftime`](http://php.net/strftime) does.

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'german');
echo (iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8', strftime('%Y. %B %d. (%A)', mktime('0', '0', '0', '6', '18', '2010'))));

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'hungarian');
echo (iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8', strftime('%Y. %B %d. (%A)', mktime('0', '0', '0', '6', '18', '2010'))));
```

Comment: May you explain what the `iconv` is for here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strftime`](http://php.net/strftime) for local date:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT');
$timestamp = strtotime("31-12-2012");
echo strftime("%A", $timestamp);
```