# intldateformatter date with short month names and days of the week

Tags: php, date, localization

I am using IntlDateFormatter to format dates with the "FULL" constant, which turns out like:

> Thursday, August 29, 2013

How can I get dates with short weekdays/month names like:

> Thu, Aug 29, 2013

instead? So something like "MEDIUM" style plus weekday.

Comment: hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992296/localized-short-month-names-using-intldateformatter-in-php/13993193#13993193

Comment: http://in1.php.net/intldateformatter.setpattern

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is readily available in the [manual](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime).

Comment: the pattern for the IntlDateFormatter 'EEE, MMM dd, yyyy' in your case.

Comment: Thanks. I actually have dates in three languages (English, German, Polish) and each language uses a different month/day order. Does this mean that I would have to create date-formats for each of these three languages? I kind of liked the idea that the predefined constants like FULL took care of the date formatting without me having to think whether it is "Aug 29" or "29. Aug" or ...

Comment: i dont know whether the sate formats matter bcoz we are formatting it again..just try it and see